# How to reuse Nginx configuration among blocks?

Tags: nginx, dry, code-reuse

Consider this configuration:

```
location /ar {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:52056;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite ^/ar/(.*)$ /$1?local=ar;
    rewrite ^/ar /?local=ar;
}

location /ru {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:52056;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite ^/ru/(.*)$ /$1?local=ru;
    rewrite ^/ru /?local=ru;
}
```

As you can see, a lot of lines are duplicates between these two blocks.

How can I reuse them?

Comment: With [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) statement.